# I want to smuggle an integer out of a function in a list without changing its elements or increasing memory usage

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function

```python3
def in_place_modify(arr):
    # arr is modified in-place here.
    return arr
```

I want to store an integer `i` somewhere on `arr` as it's returned out of the function, and then retrieve `i` in the following way:

```python3
in_place_modify(arr)
i = ...    # something involving `arr`
```

However, I want to do so without changing the major functionality of the list object `arr`

- The content `arr[i]` should not be changed.
- The string representation (`__repr__` and `__str__`) shouldn't change.
- I don't want to introduce new memory if I can help it: I want to reuse existing memory if I can.

However, much of the list object properties are read only.

Is there a way to do this without extra memory and without breaking the list-ness of the list?

Comment: Would it work to make it a global varibable

Comment: @TERMINATOR No, that allocates new memory.